# split json file into smaller files?

Tags: json

I have a JSON file `nan-0-18.json` which follows the format

```
{"event_type": "surge", , ....., "timestamp":"01-01-01', "local_pref": 0, "packets": 4, "bytes": 54, "writer_id": "ad"},
```

the file has about 13000 of these flows but i want to divide them into 2 `json` files `nan-0-18-1.json` and `nan-0-18-2.json` such that they are still chronological. I am not used to `json` at all and wanted to know if anyone could provide any help for that?